# Discord.js - having problem with fetchInvites()

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am getting this error

> ENTERED INVITE
>   (node:1772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>   (node:1772) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process wi
>   th a non-zero exit code.

When I try to gather invite data. Here is the code I am using

```
const invitesCalc = (bot, msg, cmd) => {
    const richEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
    let user = msg.author.id;
    let max = 0;
    let numberUses;
    let invites = msg.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then(result => {
            let inviteArr = result.array();
            for (let i = 0; i < inviteArr.length; i++) {
                let invite = inviteArr[i];
                console.log("ENTERED INVITE");
                if (invite.inviter.id === user) {
                    numberUses = invite.uses;

                    if (numberUses > max) {
                        max = numberUses;
                    }
                }
                console.log("EXIT INVITE");
            }
```

It works on my test server but not on my actual server with a lot of users on it. The code only gets to ENTERED INVITE but errors at the if statement with `invite.inviter.id === user`

Comment: try this `if (invite.inviter  && invite.inviter.id === user)`

Comment: The docs for [`Invite`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite) show `The only guaranteed properties are code, guild and channel. Other properties can be missing.` so `inviter` may not always be available